# Get the parent/grandparent without knowing the structure?

Tags: jquery

It is basic. I need to use a single statement that return the parent

1.

```
<div id="1">
   <div id="2">
      <div id="3"></div>
   </div>

</div>
```

So given element `id=3` , **or** given element `id=2`, i get element with **id=1**.
Assuming i don't know if I am calling on element 2 or 3, i need the grand parent that *is not the body*.

`element.parent()` , or `element.parent().parent()`, are not good because i don't know the structure, only want the "main" parent.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean. grand parent will be always <html>. What's the criteria to decide your "grand parent"?

Comment: @TomaszBucko sorry i was using the wrong term "grand". i just need to get id=1 from any level, without knowing what level.

Comment: LOL, then you can get simply using $('#your-id-string')

Comment: @TomaszBucko its not lol, because as i said, i do not know the structure, that's including the ID. i just know the ID level i begin with(ex 3), and i need that "group's" parent.

Comment: Not clear yet. please paste some code you are trying or example. current posted example is so simple and I can't guess what you mean.

Comment: what i mean is pretty clear in the question. given element 2 or 3, i need to get element 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215739/discussion-between-tomasz-bucko-and-paul-seems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$(element).closest('body>*')`. `closest` will find `parent` or `parent of parent` or so on until it will find matching `selector`. In your case `selector` is `immediate` `child` of `body` so use `body>*`.

Test it here.

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  alert($(this).closest('body>*').attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1">
  <div id="2">
    <div id="3">
      <input type="button" value="Get Parent" class="btn" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="11">
  <div id="12">
    <div id="13">
      <div id="14">
        <input type="button" value="Get Parent" class="btn" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow thanks !! is this the simplest way to do so? i was thinking JQ has some single word (eg .parent), that get you the parent of a certain "group" in the document ( which sounds like a very popular need)